# How to transform this object?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I need to make the highlighted object shear itself into the shape of the poly behind it but the shear tool will only let me do it one way and won't let me align vertices.
I had some luck with proportional transforming but it still wasn't perfect. I need it to be perfect down to the vertex.
What do?

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already tried proportional editing, but I think you ought to be able to get what you're looking for using it.

Try selecting the bottom edges and scaling it down with proportional editing and linear falloff. You'll then need to use the mouse wheel to adjust the proportional editing size.

If any vertices are slightly off, you can grab them and snap them to the edges of the bottom mesh.

[image]